# Android - Using large images in an ImageView or different sized images

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

I have a "dashboard" menu that works great on Android. It has eight ImageViews and works just as I need it.

```
-------------------
|        |        |
|    1   |    2   |
-------------------
-------------------
|        |        |
|   3    |    4   |
-------------------
-------------------
|        |        |
|    5   |    6   |
-------------------
-------------------
|        |        |
|    7   |    8   |
-------------------
```

I use 8 different images at a very high resolution so that they look good everywhere. I don't include any of them in different dpi folders. I just have one large resolution that all screen sizes pick up. Is this bad practice? Should I really have different sized images for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this bad practice?

If it looks good at all screen densities (and sizes that you are supporting), this is perfectly fine. Only you can make that determination.

As I note in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13521317/115145), the issue is the automatic resampling, and the resulting quality.

First, screen densities keep increasing. We have `-xxhdpi` devices now (e.g., Droid DNA). However, `-xxhdpi` was a relatively recent addition to the SDK. If your icons are `-xhdpi`, they will be upsampled for `-xxhdpi`, and that could be problematic. At the moment, `-xxhdpi` devices are extremely few in number, though, so this may not matter for the moment. However, if you are only supplying, say, `-mdpi` images, Android will need to upsample for `-hdpi` on up, once again likely causing artifacts.

Downsampling is more likely to have decent results, compared with upsampling. However, it is not an absolute guarantee of quality, particularly as you go through several levels (e.g., downsampling `-xhdpi` to `-ldpi`).

Custom-crafting images for other densities give you absolute control over quality, at the cost of development time and APK size.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to know. Is the Nexus 10 xxhdpi? I've loaded up some of my sample applications onto my Nexus 10 and they look fine (apps look exactly like they do on my samsung galaxy tab). I thought with the extremely high ppi there would be some problems right out of the box. Any quick notes regarding that?

Comment: @EGHDK: "Is the Nexus 10 xxhdpi?" -- no, *except* for launcher icons, for some goofy reason.

Comment: What? So technically, my launcher icons on my Nexus 10 are being upsampled?

Comment: @EGHDK: AFAIK, yes. See: https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW