# Using one ic_launcher.png instead of four

Tags: android, icons

Is there any reason (besides having physically different looking icons) to include four different sizes of my launcher icon? I would think if I just included one icon in my app (in xhdpi directory), the ldpi devices would just use the xhdpi icon and scale it appropriately.

[image]

Comment: I do that all the time (one icon on hdpi, though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the ldpi devices would just use the xhdpi icon and scale it appropriately

Correct. And you have absolutely no control over the quality of the result.

So, *if* you try this for an image (launcher icon or any other) and *if* the results are acceptable on all major screen densities, go for it. However, there may be some images where the degraded results from the downsampling means that you will want to supply your own images at other densities, where you have more control over the results.

Comment: Hmm... so they could potentially look bad because of downsampling. Did not think about that. Could you possibly provide some insight on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961984/android-using-large-images-in-an-imageview-or-different-sized-images

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use 4 instead of just 1 is the same as with any other image on your app (i.e., to avoid scaling and to ensure drawables look their best on any device). The difference is that the launcher icon is small, so the scaling won't have such a big impact (i.e., shouldn't be noticeable unless you pay a lot of attention to it).

I also use only a couple of icon versions on most of my apps, though for clients I'll provide one for every dpi.